# Term for "pre-login" pages

Tags: terminology

When using a web application, there are certain pages displayed "outside" of the main application, typically prior to login.

Examples include: Login, recover password, registration, etc.

Some time ago I heard a word used to refer to these pages, but for the life of me I can't remember what it was.

Is anyone aware of a word used to refer to such pages?

Comment: From the development point of view those are pages related to "accounts" and "authentication". For example: when I develop such pages, the templates for them are in an "auth" folder. I don't know if there's a more common, specific term, though. "Gateway", "transitional", ... now I'm only guessing.

Comment: I'd say "identity" is a related term, too.

Answer (score 8):

Registration pages possibly but I'd generally refer to them all as

**Public pages / public site**

That is all the parts that are accessible to the general public of the Internet, it could be registration, about, contact, info but nothing behind the security doors.

Answer (score 2):

A term that has been used for the processes (and therefore) pages that a user goes through before becoming an accepted/registered user is **onboarding**. It is something that I see used in government or corporate circles, not necessarily user-friendly but popular enough to some degree.

Comment: This is the term I was thinking, it only really works if the visible pages are intended to entice/allow the user to go to the "inside" of the main application but seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

Another term I've heard used is *Anonymous* pages.

Answer (score 2):

Collectively named our **"public-facing site"** we referred to pages like our individual account sign-up (non-paying student athlete users), school registration sign-ups (requiring more authentication and handling payments), our "onboarding" page demonstrating different packages and features, free trial sign-up, and auth/logged-out pages as **"public-facing pages"**.

That naming continued to work once we started public blogs, and when we added another feature leading to a page for every athlete that had a "**public-facing" version** that showed only certain items, and then a logged-in version with much more info.

In the dev/QA/PM/design trenches, we occasionally interchanged **"logged-out version"** to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like **"Authentication forms"** or **"Authentication pages"**.

Those were the terms I used when creating [mockups with Balsamiq](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/web/Authentication%20Forms).

A "Password Recovery" page could also be part of several **["Self-service pages"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-service_password_reset)**.

Answer (score 1):

In our Design team, we refer to this as "Landing Page". The Page that comes up after user signs-in or logs-in we refer to as Home Page.

Comment: yes, this or Splash Page are teh most common

Answer (score 0):

We refer to folks who come to the site, but are not logged in as VISITORS. Once they log in, they are USERS. We reference pages with that nomenclature, too, as we have some state-dependent pages.

Comment: What about "external unauthenticated" pages?

Answer (score 0):

I currently work at a bank and prior to that at some other industries where such pages existed, I have always heard them referred to as NLI pages (not logged in)